# Accessing second localhost DB from within WordPress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a MySQL db, accessed via some PHP scripts. I wish to embed these scripts within WordPress Page templates, in a WordPress install running from the same server (i.e. 'localhost').

I know that the scripts work absolutely fine outside WordPress, but, once placed within a template only the markup is executed - no data is filled in. No MySQL errors are generated.

Is there some issue with connecting to another db from within WordPress? Do I need to couch my queries in some manner? I include below the template code, and the mysql connect.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Profile Page
*/
get_header(); ?>

        <div id="pedigree-content">
            <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' ); ?>
            <?php include 'profile.php'; ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

'profile.php' is called successfully, and includes within itself the connect:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);
?>
```

The query runs, and then the connection is closed via mysql_close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`wpd` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Notes_On_Use) to instantiate a connection to another database. The recommended approach to connecting to another / multiple databases is to use a plugin called [HyperDB](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hyperdb/) which will simplify this for you.